# PuTTY connection to remote server freezing sporadically

Tags: networking, server, ssh, putty

I'm using PuTTY to connect to a remote Ubuntu server hosted on AWS. Every now and then the connection completely freezes and nothing I do makes it respond. It comes back by itself after a few minutes and then tries to apply all the gibberish I typed while trying to get it to respond.

Is there a way to avoid these freezes/minutes long lags and if not, is there a way know when it's happening, vs the keystrokes are reaching the server but have no effect in the current context?

Comment: Sounds like a network connectivity issue between you and the server.  What kind of internet connection are you accessing this from, and have you ever tried accessing it from a different internet connection?

Have you made any modifications to the server eg setting up a firewall, and if so, what settings?

Comment: @thomasrutter It's a workplace network. Everything else still works, including PuTTY sessions to other AWS machines. No firewall changes have been made recently, and that's not part of my job. So far I've had 2 freezes in 2 days, but I'm not using PuTTY 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for your problem is when the server thinks the SSH session is inactive. There are two keepalive options in PuTTY in the category *Connection*; you can try if it gets better when one or both are enabled:

- *Seconds between keepalives*: Set to something like 10 or 20.
- *Enable TCP keepalives*